# Can faster I/O reduce page splits in indexes?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

**CONTEXT**

I came across a site where someone says that Faster hardware can reduce page splitting.

This doesn't make sense to me, as per my understanding page splits are related with page size/page filling, and not with I/O performance.

**QUESTION**

Can faster I/O reduce page splits in indexes?

If yes, how does it reduce page splitting?

I believe that this guy wants to say that faster hardware can make the page splitting more unnoticed on a performance level, which is something completely different.

[A faster hardware system can also reduce page splits](https://www.careerride.com/SQL-Server-what-is-page-splits.aspx) (CTRL + F this text to find the complete post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're right.

A faster I/O can speed up a system in total, but it does not influence the algorithm.
So the author probably meant the system performance.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I've Acknowledge your answer, I'll wait a little bit more for eventual more answers before accepting. Thanks for your contribution, so far.